# How to create a "next" button that switches tabs using Java Script and Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, button, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/h6rQ2/2/

I'm using html to create a basic form. This form has two sections -- each section is contained within a tab (tabs created with Twitter Bootstrap).

How do I create a "next" button which switches from the first tab to the second tab? When I try doing it right now, it only submits the form. Does Twitter Bootstrap already provide a function that lets you switch tabs via an external button? If so, how do you use it?

Comment: What have you tried? [This](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs) shows you how to select a specific tab using JS. Now you just need to figure out how to get the next sibling of the current element.

Comment: I created a button that calls the following function:   $(function next () {$('#tab_bar a:last').tab('show');}). I get two problems though: (1) When I first load the page, the second tab is already active whereas I want the first tab to be active (2) When I press the button, it submits the form before switching to the second tab. I'm new at this so I'm sure I'm ignoring something important

Comment: I had a feeling the functions that are given with Twitter Bootstrap could be used to accomplish what I need. But I'm not sure how to use them exactly

Comment: Why all the downvotes? There's even a fiddle provided!

Comment: did u try with e.preventDefault()?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Given those buttons :

```html
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn" id="prevtab" type="button">Prev</button>
    <button class="btn" id="nexttab" type="button">Next</button>
</div>
```

You'd need this JS :

```js
var $tabs = $('.tabbable li');

$('#prevtab').on('click', function() {
    $tabs.filter('.active').prev('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');
});

$('#nexttab').on('click', function() {
    $tabs.filter('.active').next('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');
});
```

[Working demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/h6rQ2/3/)

Comment: Is there a certain way I should add the javascript? I copy-pasted your javascript code into a separate file, and called that file in the head of my html. It's still not working though, and I'm at the end of my rope.

Comment: ok, after some extensive testing, I'm pretty sure I'm not loading your javascript properly. This is how I've currently done it: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script> with your code simply copy-pasted into the file "custom.js". Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @goelv You need to *wait* for dom ready to do that. The demo is working because jsfiddle does it by default. Check [this doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3), and put my code inside a function that will be called only after the dom is ready.

Comment: Wow, i have a lot to learn about javascript. Thank you SO MUCH, it works perfectly!

Comment: Doesn't work for tabs with dropdown options in them. seems to activate all tabs in the dropdown. any solution?

Comment: @user1862764 you should try it out in a fiddle and change the selector in the `find()`, if you still do not resolve it, ask a new question

Answer (score 1):

To make it cyclic (last tab goes to first, first tab goes to last), here is my code :

```
function previousVin(){
    var previousElement = $('#myTab li').filter('.active').prev('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]');
    if(previousElement.html()===undefined){
        $('#myTab a:last').tab('show');
    }else{
        previousElement.tab('show');
    }
}
function nextVin(){
    var nextElement = $('#myTab li').filter('.active').next('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]');
    if(nextElement.html()===undefined){
        $('#myTab a:first').tab('show');
    }else{
        nextElement.tab('show');
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For bootstrap 3

```
$('a[data-toggle^="tab"]').click(function(){
    var data = $(this).attr("href");
    $('a[data-toggle^="tab"]').parent("li").removeClass("active");
    $('li a[href^="'+data+'"]').parent("li").addClass("active");
    $('.tab-pane').removeClass("active");
    $(data).addClass("active");
})
```

You can add links like these anywhere

```
<a href="#tabname2" data-toggle="tab">Next</a>
<a href="#tabname1" data-toggle="tab">Previous</a>
```